# Create summary stats using Revolution R/ScaleR

Tags: r, revolution-r

im new to ScaleR/RevoR - I have a .xdf data set that has 400+ 'parts' and each part has 70000 numerical values....so the data set is quite large >40 million rows.
I'd like to use RevoR to give me the Median & Mode for each 'part'...I can get the  Mean & std dev using rxSummary..? but how does one compute the mode & median..?

Also, once I have a summarized .xdf file 400+ rows long housing the part, Mode & Median..how can I convert it back to a dataframe in memory..? I've been trying rxReadXdf and ive been getting this error:

Error in rxLocateFileInternal(file, pathsToSearch, fileSystem, isOutFile = isOutFile,  : 
  sum not found in paths .; Working dir is: /seamnt/sasdata-stage/RStudio/Workspaces/myname

Any help would be appreciated..
Paul.

Answer (score 4):

At the moment, you can't natively get the mode and median from `rxCube` or `rxSummary`.

One workaround is to split your dataset by your 'part', convert each portion into a data frame, and then get the mode/median using standard R functions. The code will look something like this:

```
# split the data by 'part' variable (which has to be a factor)
xdfList <- rxSplit(baseXdf, outFilesBase="base", splitByFactor="part")

smry <- rxExec(function(xdf) {
        df <- rxImport(xdf)
        # median of a numeric variable
        xmed <- median(df$x)
        # mode of a factor variable
        ftab <- table(df$f)
        fmode <- names(ftab)[which.max(ftab)]
        data.frame(part=as.character(df$part), xmed=xmed, fmode=fmode)
    }, xdf=rxElemArg(xdfList))

smry <- do.call(rbind, smry)
```

Or if you have the [dplyrXdf package](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2015/10/the-dplyrxdf-package.html), you can leverage `dplyr::summarise` to compute the median (if not the mode) for you:

```
baseXdf %>% group_by(part) %>%
    summarise(xmed=median(x))
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of dplyrXdf.